# TPNGImage `LoadFromStream` is not working in some cases

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe, vcl

I'm using VCL `TPNGImage` class to load PNG images. If I create the `TPNGImage` object using `FindClass(S).Create`(`S` is a `String` and it might contain `'TPNGImage'`), when I try to load the png image using `LoadFromStream` I fade an access violation exception. Do you have any ideas?

Note that I use the following code to create a new instance:

```
P := TPNGImage(FindClass('tpngimage').NewInstance);
```

Comment: Why are you using that `FindClass('TPNGImage')` statement. Do you have a reason for that ?

Comment: `uses PNGImage` is what you need

Comment: Definitely. It's actually a string variable instead of a 'TPNGImage'.

Comment: @David: Nope, didn't work.

Comment: Have you tried: `P := TPNGImage(FindClass('tpngimage')).Create`

Comment: @kobik: Yes, it doesn't work.

Comment: @Kobik That would not be it. You need to cast to `TGraphicClass` and call the constructor on that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You say that you create the class by calling:

```
P := TPNGImage(FindClass('tpngimage').NewInstance);
```

That code will allocate an instance, but will not run the constructor. And that is your problem. You cannot expect an instance to work if you have not constructed it properly.

You need to use

```
P := TPNGImage.Create;
```

---

Now, it sounds as though you want to be able to write code that can work on a variety of `TGraphic` descendent. You can make that work.

First of all declare your variable to be of type `TGraphic`.

```
var
  Image: TGraphic;
```

And then get hold of a class reference.

```
var
  Cls: TPersistentClass;
....
Cls := FindClass('TPNGImage');
```

And then instantiate the object, if the class reference is compatible.

```
if Cls.InheritsFrom(TGraphic) then
  Image := TGraphicClass(Cls).Create;
```

Because `TGraphic` uses a virtual constructor that will run the `TPNGImage` constructor. You could use this same code to construct JPEG, BMP, GIF etc.

Comment: Exactly! While I was waiting for an answer, I tried this code and it worked: `P := TPNGImage(TGraphicClass(FindClass('TPNGImage')).Create);`

Comment: If you know you want `TPNGImage` then you should write `TPNGImage.Create`. But I guess you want to be able to create instances of a graphic class specified by name. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes of course. I know it's definitely better to use `TPNGImage.Create` when I can; but what I'm trying to do is to save and load any image to an stream. In this case, first, I write the name of the class in the stream and then I create the graphic class.